# TYPO3 v11.5 bootstrap package. How to get the category title in the menu_sitemap component element for each page?

Tags: typo3, categories, sitemap

In TYPO3 v11.5 (bootstrap package) I'm using the menu_sitemap component element. How can I access in Fluid the category name for each displayed page?

Thank you for your reply.

I'm looking for a solution by modifing the MenuSitemap.typoscript file.

```
tt_content.menu_sitemap =< lib.contentElement
tt_content.menu_sitemap {
    templateName = MenuSitemap
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
            levels = 7
            dataProcessing {
                10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                10 {
                    references.fieldName = media
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stdWrap {
        # @deprecated since v11: stdWrap.editIcons. Will be removed with v12.
        editIcons = tt_content: header [header_layout], pages
        editIcons {
            iconTitle.data = LLL:EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Language/FrontendEditing.xlf:editIcon.menu
        }
    }
}
```